# Bluetooth Heaphones connect but don't output sound [Ubuntu 20.04]

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, headphones

My Bluetooth headphones can pair and connect to my laptop, but they do not show up in the audio options, and I cannot obtain sound output through them. The problem started suddenly about 2 weeks back -- sometime after performing an apt-get update/upgrade, and I've been struggling to fix it ever since. I've tried numerous suggestions to similar past questions, but none of them seem to work for me.

The headphones still work perfectly fine on other laptops and my phone. Basically, when I initially connect them to this laptop, the Bluetooth connects and immediately disconnects, and the Bluetooth settings page sort of refreshes. After this refresh, I can stably connect my Bluetooth headphones, but there is a catch - although it shows connected on my laptop, the light on the headphones still indicates that the headphone is waiting to connect.

I've tried reinstalling PulseAudio and alsa and all their related files, but to no avail. I tried modifying the /etc/pulse/default.pa and /etc/bluetooth/main.conf files as suggested in similar problems - no change. I also tried reinstalling the kernel as a last-ditch effort - no luck.

I'm relatively new to the Linux ecosystem; pardon me if I am missing something obvious. Also, let me know if any output dump of any command is needed to better gauge my issue.

I've been trying to solve this problem for the past 2 weeks, and I cannot resolve it. It has had a massive negative impact on my daily workflow, and I would really appreciate any help you guys can provide... Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing Blueman and check if it detects your bluetooth headphones.

```
sudo apt install bluez bluez-tools
sudo apt install blueman
```

You can either run these commands or install Bluetooth Manager from your Ubuntu store.